# How to Detect Changes on New Radio Buttons?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, radio-button, jquery-events

I have code that detects a radio button change and then calls a method on the button. It works fine on existing buttons, but when I add new radio buttons to the page (through ajax), it doesn't work on them. How do I get it to detect changes on new radio buttons?

This is my coffeescript code:

```
jQuery ->
    $(".radio-button:radio").change ->
        doSomething(this)
```

Which looks like this in JS:

```
jQuery(function() {
  return $(".radio-button:radio").change(function() {
    return doSomething(this);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dynamically created elements, you need do event delegation using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('change','.radio-button:radio', function() {
    //Your code here
});
```

instead of (for static elements)

```
$(".radio-button:radio").change(function() {
    //Your code
});
```

Note: You need to replace `$(document)` with a static parent selector `$(parent)` which is present in DOM & use that for better performance.

Comment: Thanks. No lower parent exists on page load, so I guess I'll stick with document.